# Integrating $\frac{1}{1+z}$ along a path to derive the Maclaurin series for $\mathrm{Log}(1+z)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

> Integrate the Maclaurin series for$\frac{1}{1+z}$ along a path, inside
>   the circle of convergence, going from $z'=0$ to $z'=z$ and show that
>   $$Log(z+1)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac{z^n}{n}, \space |z|<1$$

My attempt
$$\frac{1}{1+z}=\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^n z^n\Rightarrow \int \frac{1}{1+z}=Log(z+1)=\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^{n+1}\frac{z^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

I don't know how to get this expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a small problem with your integration.
$$\int(-1)^n\frac{z^n}n=(-1)^n\frac{z^{n+1}}{n+1}.$$
Now you're almost there. 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac {z^{n+1}}{n+1}=\sum_{m=1}^\infty(-1)^{m-1}\frac{z^m}m.$$
where $m=n+1$. Note that $(-1)^{m-1}=(-1)^{m+1}$. You do have to show that the constant of integration is $0$.

Comment: His first integral is right? In the second part you did not derived only took a few terms out and showed that the constant is 0?

Comment: The second is a change of index.

Comment: You trade $n$ for $n-1$ right? But that still does not prove equal, because the exponent of -1

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: Now I understand, but I could do without changing the variable right? Because $(-1)^{n-1}=(-1)^{n+1}$ or no?

Comment: There's no need to change the variable. I only did so to point out the change of index.